# Some PCA loadings of a given matrix in MATLAB and Python produce opposite signs. While the magnitude is the same, I require same signs for summation

Tags: python, matlab, cross-platform, pca, svd

I have a matrix X of which, upon centering, I perform SVD. While I get the same magnitude of the loadings, some of the columns produce opposite signs between MATLAB and Python. I understand the opposite signs do not matter as far as the PCA is concerned, however, I need to perform summation of the loading values later on. This causes difference in the results between MATLAB and Python. Therefore, I need same signs of loadings across both MATLAB and Python. What could I do to get the same signs in both the platforms? I am using np.linalg.svd() function in Python and simple svd() function in MATLAB. Please help.

Intriguingly, when X is not centered, I get same signs. I tried sklearn.decomposition.PCA() function in Python as well but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can, for example, flip the vector if the first component is negative. That way you can enforce the same signs in both code bases.

Comment: The problem is I assume that I "wouldn't" know which columns have opposite signs between MATLAB and Python. Most of the columns have the same sign. Flipping was ideal if I knew "in advance" which columns to flip.

Comment: Flip the vector **if the first component is negative**. Do that in both code bases, and both code bases will have the same signs.

Comment: You might need to special-case for the first component being zero, since that doesn't have a sign. It being identical to zero is highly unlikely, but everything is possible, and you might want to take that into account.

Comment: That is an interesting solution and should work. But then again, there is another issue - I am translating MATLAB code into Python and I CANNOT tamper with the MATLAB code. I am highly restrained here.